# Changing hover color of a TButton in a C++Builder Firemonkey program

Tags: c++, colors, hover, firemonkey, c++builder

Is there a way of changing the mouse hover color of a styled `TButton` in a C++Builder Firemonkey app for Windows?

Eg: I have a `TButton` on a form that uses the AquaGraphite style. The button is a start / stop button, and I want it to be green when it says "Start" in the text, and Red when it says "Stop".  I can change the color of the button ok from Green to Red and back again.  But, when I hover the mouse over it, it changes the color to the applied style of the form (a blue color).

Is there a way of changing the hover color on a `TButton` in FireMonkey? Or better yet, can I remove the hovering effect?

Comment: How are you changing the button colour to Green and Red?  Via a style, or some other way?

Comment: I use a little code snippet I found on the Internet:

https://learncplusplus.org/how-to-change-background-color-of-a-component-in-an-fmx-c-app/

Comment: Okay, so you change the background in code at runtime?  That is, you don't do anything at design time?

Comment: https://youtu.be/qWsrlUo0nIk you can use TStyleBook for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, but the steps are basically as follows:

1. Right-click on your button (in the form designer) and choose the option 'Edit custom style'.  This will place you in the style editor, with a new style named after your button.
2. Expand this style in the Structure view.
3. Click on the `Background` component.[image: The structure view]
4. In the Object Inspector, you will see four 'link' properties (in the case of a `TButton`): `FocusedLink` (see image), `HotLink`, `NormalLink`, and `PressedLink`.  Click on the button in one of these fields to change it.  This will bring up the BitmapLinks Editor.  Take note of the images there, and the nested dotted rectangles with handles, around a button image.[image]
5. Click the Images 'Open' button, and find and select a bitmap with the button images you would like, but with your preferred colours.  (You will need to create this separately.)  You can base this on the images you saw when opening the BitmapLinks Editor.  Your bitmap can have separate images for all four 'links' (states), or only have two or three button images if you prefer.  (Just close the 'Editing TImageMultiResBitmap' box that opens.)
6. Use the handles of the outer rectangle to drag that rectangle to your own button images.
7. Repeat this for each of the four 'links'.  I don't know if you can disable the hover one (`HotLink`).  You *could* make it the same colour as one of the others, but if the button is green and hover is red, you'd get red when hovering over a green button.
8. Close the Style Designer tab, clicking Yes to the prompt about saving it.

Comment: Thanks Philip.  However, when I click on the 'Edit Custom Style' option, in the style editor, there is no Background component.  There is a backgroundstyle component but there are no links in it as you suggest.  There is a background component under the ButtonStyle component.  However, there are no link properties as you mentioned.  I am using C++ Builder 11.1.5.

Comment: I use Delphi, not C++, but I assume that the FireMonkey components are the same in both cases.  If not, then sorry for wasting your time.  But for clarity, I have added pictures to illustrate, in case you misunderstood something.

Answer (score 0):

AquaGraphite's button have a complex style structure but with rectangle objects for background (@Philip not a Styleobject one)

You can remove/change colors or effects at in a custom style
[image: like this]

> Change color when green when it says "Start" in the text, and Red when
> it says "Stop".

It's not possible to make this change at design time except if you create another custom style (one for each ie. buttonstartStyle, buttonStopStyle)
You'll still have to change stylelookup at runtime (easy way)
Note : in this style, background is filled by a gradient not a color.

You can also add an effect (TGradientAnimation) to your buttonstyle.background but no trigger can be associated to a text change. (ischecked=true, ischecked=false is irrelevant even if possible et design)

[image: adding an animation]

I try this in Delphi (don't have C++) like this

```
var effect : TFMXObject;
begin
 Effect:=Button1.FindStyleResource('startstopcolor',false);
 if Sametext(button1.Text,'start') then
  begin
    Button1.Text:='Stop';
    if assigned(effect) AND (Effect is TGradientAnimation) then
    begin
     TGradientAnimation(effect).Inverse:=False;
     TGradientAnimation(effect).Start;
    end;
  end
  else begin
   Button1.Text:='Start';
    if assigned(effect) AND (Effect is TGradientAnimation) then
      begin
       TGradientAnimation(effect).Inverse:=true;
       TGradientAnimation(effect).Start;
      end;
  end;
```

Comment: Ah, I see.  It's not a Delphi/C++ difference (I didn't think it would be), but a different style structure with that style, whereas I was using the default style, assuming that the only difference was with the bitmap.  I've not used other styles much, and not tried modifying them when I have.